# Как поставить логотип в phpbb версии 3.2

Tags: php, phpbb

Помогите пожалуйста как поставить свой логотип на phpbb форуме? Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен Ftp клиент, вам нужно загрузить изображение сюда: /styles/prosilver/theme/images/ (если вы используйте тему prosilver) можете дать имя site_logo.gif, такое же как оригинальное лого.

Comment: А насчет локальной сети?

Comment: используйте тот же путь

Comment: Я заменил его теперь без логотипа стоит

Comment: почему без логотипа?

Comment: Спасибо я разобрался надо было в разделе администратора "Нагрузка на сервер" - отметить обновление контента и я с помощью url поставил свое лого, а так не читает локальный путь